# Google hates my RDFa phone number

Tags: html, schema

What's wrong with this code? Google's structured data tool says "telephone [Unspecified type]:" The rest of the schema works fine. I'd love to know why it's kicking it out.

```
<div class="columns small-12 medium-4 contact" vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="LocalBusiness">
        <a property="telephone" class="phone" href="tel:+15032418234">503 241 8234</a><br />

        <a href="mailto:info@moderninterface.com" class="ulink">info@moderninterface.com</a><br/>

        <a property="address" typeof="PostalAddress" class="addy map" href="http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=1001+SE+Water+Ave,Portland,OR">
            <span property="streetAddress">1001 SE Water Avenue, Suite 330</span><br />
            <span property="addressLocality">Portland</span>,
            <span property="addressRegion">Oregon</span>
            <span property="postalCode">97214</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It wants a `content` property for the phone number. It has the same problem with email addresses.

```
<a property="telephone" class="phone" href="tel:+15032418234" content="+15032418234">503 241 8234</a>
```